# CUDA: Particle method, ID assignment to newly created particles in the Threads

Tags: cuda, synchronization

I have a problem in my project. It is in particle method and particles have their own properties like ID velocity pressure etc. The calculation is done in GPU, one thread per particle. Now when the particle splits, say into 3. The new particles need ID but the problem is multiple splitted particles from multiple threads try to assign the same particle ID. I currently did that using `__syncthreads()` but it is slow. Is there any other way to achieve that?

Comment: I'm not sure if your question can be related to CUDA programming at all. Maybe there aren't enough provided info to answer it. Anyways, a simple and fast solution can be done by shifting parent indices. Let's say you have some particles at the beginning, identified with `pID` from 0 to `nParticles-1`. Let's say each parent can make 3 children with `cID` 1 to 3. A unique ID for each particle at each step can be made with `(pID<<2)|cID` for children particles and with `(pID<<2)` for parent particles.

Answer (score 2):

The use of synchronization for ID generation does not seem to be justified in this case.

You can try to assign a ID based on the ID of the parent particle. For example, you could include the parent's particle ID in the child's ID. So, the child ID could be ..

```
to_int(string(parent_id) + string(child_no))
```